# webpack 5 ssr with react adds margin top to the body tag

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

Webpack 5 SSR with react is pushing down the body tag by some pixels. Not able to find the issue. Help me if anyone found anything. Providing the code here.

On express side

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.send(renderer());
});
```

Inside renderer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import App from "../../client/components/App";

export default () => {
    const content = renderToString(<App />);

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Container App</title>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root">
                ${content}
            </div>
            <script async src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>`;
}
```

Inside App.js

```
import React from "react";

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

The html document's is contained correctly while the body tag gets pushed down. Any idea why this happens?

CSS for the body is as given below.

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

If you guys have any idea about this. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: This is not related to webpack, react or SSR. It is basic HTML/CSS. `<h1>` elements have top and bottom margins by default. This is why your seems to be 'pushed down'. Try removing those margins and you'll see your body tag is just fine.

Comment: @BaptisteF. tried removing the h1 and used div instead still it's the same.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot after replacing the `h1` with `div` tag?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
 }
```